# About the time complexity algorithm and asymptotic growth

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I've got the question about the time complexity algorithm and asymptotic growth.
The pseudo code of question is

```
1: function NAIVE(x,A)
2:  answer = 0
3:  n= length of A
4:  for I from - to n do
5:    aux = 1
6.    for j from 1 to I do
7:     aux = aux*x
8:    answer = answer + aux * A[I]
9.  return answer
```

I have to find upperbound with O-notation and lowerbound witn Ω-notation.
I got the time complexity f(n) = 5n^2 + 4n + 8 and g(n) = n^2.
My question is I'm not too sure about the running time of line number 6 to 8.
I got constant 2 and time n+1 for line number 4 and constant 1 and time 1 for line 5.
I'm stuck on after that. I tried it and I got constant 2 and time n^2 + 1 for line 6, because it runs in the for loop (for loop and for loop) so I thought its n^2+1. Is that correct?
And for line number 8 its has 3 constants and run time is n^2. is this correct? I'm not too sure about the line number 8. This is how I got f(n) = 5n^2 + 4n + 8! 
Please help me out to complete this question! 
I wonder my work is right or not!

Thank you

Comment: `for I from - to n do` ? what is it in place of `-` ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this step by step.

The complexity of line 7 `T7 = 1`.

The complexity of the surrounding `for` will be `T6(I) = I * T7 = I`.

The complexity of line 5 `T5 = 1`.

The complexity of line 8 `T8 = 1`.

The complexity of the surrounding `for` (assuming that `-` stands for 0) is

```
T4(n) = Sum{I from 0 to n} (T5 + T6(I) + T8) 
      = Sum{I from 0 to n}(2 + I)
      = Sum{I from 0 to n}(2) + Sum{I from 0 to n}(I)
      = (n + 1) * 2 + (n+1)/2 * (0 + n)
      = 2n + 2 + n^2/2 + n/2
      = 1/2 n^2 + 5/2 n + 2
```

The complexity of the remaining lines is `T2 = T3 = T9 = 1`.

The complexity of the entire algorithm is

```
T(n) = T2 + T3 + T4(n) + T9
     = 1 + 1 + 1/2 n^2 + 5/2 n + 2 + 1
     = 1/2 n^2 + 5/2 n + 5
```

This runtime is in the complexity classes `O(n^2)` and `Ω(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just bit confuse about the T4(n). Why don't you add T7 for T4(n)???

Comment: If you build an expression tree, line 7 is not directly included underneath the for statement of line 4. Instead, the other for statement (line 6) is included, which then includes line 7. You are always concerned about direct children only.